# Winged jetpack vs palm repulsors, which has more mobility in air?

Tags: technology, weapons, flight, rockets

Winged jetpack comes with 2 set of fixed thrusters and a pair of foldable wings with adjustable aileron. (You put on the jetpack like a schoolbag)

Palm repulsors are heavy duty gloves each is equipped with a powerful plasma ejector that can deliver a constant force of max 100Kg of TNT up to 2 hours. (Both repulsors work independently)

I am wondering which of these offer more versatility and dexterity in flight? Both equipment can stay levitated in-situ for a long time but I think repulsors are more tiring and maybe one setback for the repulsors is that you cannot aim your weapon and fly at the same time.

Comment: Palm repulsors=Broken arms if not part of body armor. Both will have sudden lethal G-forces as poor aerodynamics + high force=radical vector changes. Either way, it's a totally un-steerable mess (not too bad in vacuum), but in both cases, probably not a stable platform for shooting. But I have no proof for those statements, just guesses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Palm repulsors, requiring the hands to be constantly busy with keeping the right attitude, effectively hamper the bearer from using their most versatile body part: if your hands are busy keeping you in the right direction, you can't use them to hold a gun, a sandwich, not even to scratch your nose when it itches.

If you are looking for versatility, palm repulsors totally kill it.

Moreover, having the force applied away from the center of mass makes them a nightmare to control, like you can see from any slapstick movie where someone is struggling to control a hose.

Comment: Palm repulsors only look cool on Marvel's Iron Man. The torque and sheer thrust placed on flimsy arms require more shielding just to keep the limbs from breaking, which is more weight added to a flying thing, never good. And Iron Man's repulsors break physics because they don't push IM back when fired. It generates momentum out of nothing.